# Read And save custom data outside .blend

Tags: python

I need to create an addon that load and save pieces of armatures and I want to make the addon capable of loading these saved data in any file.
Almost like a preset system but with entire objects.

something like:

```
def when_addon_loads():

    data = load_from_user_settings("c:/file_path.txt")
    snippets = parse_all(data.split("\n"))
    context.scene.armature_snippets = snippets
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save individual data blocks to blend files using the `bpy.data.libraries.write()` function:

```
import bpy

filepath = "//new_library.blend"

# write selected objects and their data to a blend file
data_blocks = set(bpy.context.selected_objects)
bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks)


# write all meshes starting with a capital letter and
# set them with fake-user enabled so they aren't lost on re-saving
data_blocks = {mesh for mesh in bpy.data.meshes if mesh.name[:1].isupper()}
bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks, fake_user=True)


# write all materials, textures and node groups to a library
data_blocks = {*bpy.data.materials, *bpy.data.textures, *bpy.data.node_groups}
bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks)
```

See [the API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.write) for more info.

Comment: Is it still functional? In blender 2.93.1 it is not creating the objects .. only saves the materials.

Comment: The code is meant as an example, to be read, understood, and adjusted to your needs. If you copy-paste the code and execute it as-is, it will write the same blend file three times, each call to `bpy.data.libraries.write()` overwriting the blend file written by the previous call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer dr.Sybren. From the example, I didn't get that I must write more than the objects. If I need to save only objects, they must be written with the scene collection (I saved even a new scene for .write(). It wasn't so clear for me at the start of understanding the problem.

Comment: If you only save the objects, that means that the file won’t even have a scene. You’ll only find the objects in the Outliner, in that case.