# How to create a .blend in specific directory and write objects on it?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, blend-files

For my addon, I want to pick the selected armature and save in an external file, so I wrote the following operator for doing it:

```
class SaveArmatures(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "armature_snippets.save_armatures"
bl_label = "Save Armatures"
bl_description = ""
bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    if context.active_object:
        return context.active_object.type == "ARMATURE"

def execute(self, context):
    ob = {context.active_object}

    # Here the split method is just to get the first term of the string 
    #because it is a multifile addon
    path = context.user_preferences.addons[__name__.split(".")[0]].preferences.save_path

    bpy.data.libraries.write(os.path.join(path, "Snippets.blend"), ob, fake_user = True)
    return {"FINISHED"}
```

But when I run it raises this error.
Obviously I need to create the file first but how to do it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jea\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\Rigging_armature_snippets\loadsave.py", line 33, in execute
    bpy.data.libraries.write(os.path.join(path, "Snippets.blend"), ob, fake_user = True)
OSError: Error: Cannot open file C:\Users\Jea\Desktop\snippets\armature_snippets\Snippets.blend@ for writing: No such file or directory

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89496/read-and-save-custom-data-outside-blend

Comment: yeah, and need to creafe the file from python. Thats the problem.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/23326310/6590534

Comment: Doh, should have tested this first, rather than assume you had an existing path. Can confirm that `library.write(..)` creates a new file, as long as you have a valid path to the folder, as outlined by @aliasguru

Comment: Wieeird, why not create the file in one go since it creates the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing data into .blend files which are not existing yet works just fine. What you need to pay attention to is to make sure that **the directory** where the file is supposed to be stored in exists.

So in your given example, check if the folder `C:\Users\Jea\Desktop\snippets\armature_snippets\` exists using the os.path module, and if not, create it:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

I'm on a Linux machine here, so I cannot check if the Python implementation of these methods on Windows is case sensitive or not. On Linux it is, so '/somePath' is considered something else than '/somepath'. Maybe you came across that?

Comment: I tried and apparently bpy.data.libraries.write() does creates a directory but not the file itself.

Comment: oops, now worked, was just the wrong path, sory.